# What is the maximum Storage capacity of queued messages in Ensemble

Tags: intersystems-ensemble

Please can anyone tell what is the maximum Storage capacity of queued messages in Ensemble.
Please do the helpfull as soon as possible

Comment: Could you please provide more context? Ensemble can store messages of arbitrary size provided you have enough the disk space to store them. You may have other issues causing problems like memory caps, but it's unlikely you can't store your messages due to general Ensemble limits that can't be modified by configuration.

Comment: Hi DdP the Queued Messages are getting stored in th table "Ens.MessageHeader" with the Extent Size of 20000000.Can you say what is extent size.

Comment: The extent size is an indicator of the number of rows we expect to see in the table. You may not have that many messages, but it is used by our SQL optimizer when deciding on join order between tables of different sizes. The value here is not a limit or issue in terms of size.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit by configuration or design, every message has an ID and when a message is queued there is a persistent class `Ens.Queue` that stores the ID of the message being queued and the name of the queue where the message is queued [Ens.Queue documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20141/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=ENSLIB&CLASSNAME=Ens.Queue)